# Implementation of i2osp and os2ip

Tags: python-2.7, cryptography, rsa, pseudocode

I have a work to do in university in I have to code the RSA following the RSA-OAEP specification. My professor give me one pdf with the RFC 3447 specification.

In the pdf I have the following:

I2OSP converts a nonnegative integer to an octet string of a
   specified length.

I2OSP (x, xLen)

Input:
   x        nonnegative integer to be converted
   xLen     intended length of the resulting octet string

Output:
   X        corresponding octet string of length xLen

Error: "integer too large"

Steps:

1. If x >= 256^xLen, output "integer too large" and stop.
2. Write the integer x in its unique xLen-digit representation in
     base 256:

   ```
    x = x_(xLen-1) 256^(xLen-1) + x_(xLen-2) 256^(xLen-2) + ...
    + x_1 256 + x_0,
   ```

   where 0 <= x_i < 256 (note that one or more leading digits will be
     zero if x is less than 256^(xLen-1)).
3. Let the octet X_i have the integer value x_(xLen-i) for 1 <= i <=
     xLen.  Output the octet string

   ```
    X = X_1 X_2 ... X_xLen.
   ```

4.2 OS2IP

OS2IP converts an octet string to a nonnegative integer.

OS2IP (X)

Input:
   X        octet string to be converted

Output:
   x        corresponding nonnegative integer

Steps:

1. Let X_1 X_2 ... X_xLen be the octets of X from first to last,
     and let x_(xLen-i) be the integer value of the octet X_i for
     1 <= i <= xLen.
2. Let x = x_(xLen-1) 256^(xLen-1) + x_(xLen-2) 256^(xLen-2) + ...

   - x_1 256 + x_0.
3. Output x.

But I can't understand this pseudo-code, can someone give me one explanation how I do this? The answer can be either in pseudo-code or python implementation.

Comment: You would need to be more precise about what part is confusing you. However, we are not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: this is not doing my homework. As I said before, if you read carefully, my homework is code a python implementation of rsa with Optimal Asymmetric Encryption scheme (RSA-OAEP). You can check the document for more details in ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt I just don't understand how this data conversion primitive work reading the document. As I said, if you put pseudo-code, or explain me I would be grate to you, because I cannot understand reading the document how I have to do to convert a integer to a octet string, I don't wanna you or anyone do my homework..

Comment: By the way... I resolved the problem by my myself. Thanks to your helpfully comment, full of knowledge, you are very kind. Maybe some day I try to buy you to do the homework for me...

Comment: Basically it's a statically sized big endian encoding. If you've got it implemented you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
def i2osp(x, xLen):
        if x >= 256**xLen:
            raise ValueError("integer too large")
        digits = []

        while x:
            digits.append(int(x % 256))
            x //= 256
        for i in range(xLen - len(digits)):
            digits.append(0)
        return digits[::-1]

def os2ip(X):
        xLen = len(X)
        X = X[::-1]
        x = 0
        for i in range(xLen):
            x += X[i] * 256**i
        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript port of the Python code above, in case anyone's interested:

```js
function i2osp(x: bigint, xLen: number) {
  if (x >= BigInt(256) ** BigInt(xLen)) {
    throw new Error("integer too large");
  }
  const octets = Buffer.alloc(xLen);
  octets.forEach((_, index) => {
    octets[index] = Number(x % BigInt(256));
    x = x / BigInt(256);
  });
  return octets.reverse();
}

function os2ip(X: Buffer) {
  return Buffer.from(X).reverse().reduce(
    (total, value, index) => (total += BigInt(value * 256 ** index)),
    BigInt(0)
  );
}
```